# Create new bookmark at admin for catalog product current page

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.2.x/2.3.0
I have to create new bookmark for storing grid current page like they store pagination (20,30,50,100,200) in ui_bookmark table.

The issue is that in magneto admin if we are on 3rd page (or any page) of catalog product and edit any product of that page then click on BACK button. Now we redirect again on catalog product grid but our page reset to 1st rather than 3rd page.

How can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved grid current page issue by session. I stored current page value in session(From controller) and get on template file.